# parsing a url for the id - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following function I'm trying to implement:

```
function destroy_clusters() {
    // returns the link
    var link = document.getElementById("destroy").href;
    return false;
}
```

that will get trigged when the following click is clicked:

```
<a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/clusters/show/destroy_clusters/33/" onclick="return destroy_clusters();></a>
```

The I need to parse that link to get the id value (In that case, `33`). The problem is, I don't know even where to begin ... 
The url always have the same pattern. The only think we need to take care of is if the id is undefined or null ... which will be useful.

Comment: does the url always have the same pattern? so is "destroy_clusters/" always going to be right before the id?

Comment: Um `getElementById` but you tagged it as jQuery. I'm so confused

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
 $(function(){
      $('a').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          alert("ID" + $(this).data('id'));
          return false;
      });

 });
```

Demo:

http://code-chunk.com/chunks/543dcef720016/show-id-in-alert

html:

```
<a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/clusters/show/destroy_clusters/33/" data-id="33">ID - 33</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than parse anything, you can pass it as an argument:

```
function destroy_clusters(id) {
    // use the id here
}
```

`<a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/clusters/show/destroy_clusters/33/" onclick="return destroy_clusters(33);></a>`

Comment: The link is created by Django... `<td><a id="destroy" href="{% url "destroy_clusters" cluster.id %}" onclick="return destroy_clusters();">Delete</a></td>`. First I tried to do like you mentioned ... but I missed how to pass `cluster.id` to the function call

Answer (score 0):

```
function parseId(href) {
  var match = href.macth(/\/(\d+)\/?$/);
  return match && match[1];
}

function getId() {
  var link = document.getElementById("destroy").href;
  return = parseId(link);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript split to break up the url and return the last section.
view the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jLk7gmb8/

Javascript

```
function destroy_clusters(elem) {
    var link = elem.href;
    var splitlink = link.split("/");
    alert(splitlink[splitlink.length-2]);
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/clusters/show/destroy_clusters/33/" onclick="destroy_clusters(this);">Click Me</a>
```